# Rails: How to extract values from hash? (Amazon API / Vacuum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, amazon-product-api

How do I extract the values for title, URL and image (commented section below) from a hashed Amazon Products API response?

I'm using [Vacuum](https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum/) to interact with Amazon. Apparently I can't use `map` as `Vacuum::Response` only accepts `to_h`?

**Currently getting**:

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

**main_controller.rb**:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    request = Vacuum.new('GB')

    request.configure(
      aws_access_key_id: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST',
      aws_secret_access_key: '<long messy key>',
      associate_tag: 'lipsum-20'
    )

    params = {
      'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
      'Keywords'=> 'Ruby on Rails',
      'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images"
    }

    raw_products = request.item_search(query: params)
    hashed_products = raw_products.to_h

    # NOT WORKING

    puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title']
    puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item']['DetailPageURL']
    puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item']['LargeImage']['URL']

    # NOT WORKING

    # @products = hashed_products do |product|
    #   product.name hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title']
    #   product.url hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item']['DetailPageURL']
    #   product.image hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item']['LargeImage']['URL']
    # end

    # REDUNDANT EXAMPLE FROM OTHER PROJECT

    # @products = raw_products.map do |product|
    #   product = OpenStruct.new(product)
    #   image = product.images.find { |i| i["LargeImage"] == 'URL' }
    #   product.image = OpenStruct.new(image)
    #   product
    # end
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Products from Amazon Product Advertising API</h1>
<% if @products.any? %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product">
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.image.url), product.url %>
      <%= link_to product.name, product.url %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Full example of Amazon response can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/89d24dd88579c7f912f3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Item' is an array, so you would need to loop through it to collect the 'Title' and other attributes.  Example

```
puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].collect{|i| i['ItemAttributes']['Title']}
```

Comment: Do check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417307/rails-how-to-make-hash-values-available-to-view-amazon-api-vacuum too if you can. Bless.