# Rails: How to iterate over products from hash? (Amazon API / Vacuum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, amazon-web-services

Expanding on [Rails: How to extract values from hash? (Amazon API / Vacuum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416647/rails-how-to-extract-values-from-hash-amazon-api-vacuum) -- how do I make these newly dug up values available to my views?

**Currently getting**:

```
undefined method `image_url' for #<Hash:0x848402e0>

Extracted source (around line #5):
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), product.url %>
```

**main_controller.rb**:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    request = Vacuum.new('GB')

    request.configure(
      aws_access_key_id: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST',
      aws_secret_access_key: '<long messy key>',
      associate_tag: 'lipsum-20'
    )

    params = {
      'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
      'Keywords'=> 'Ruby on Rails',
      'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images"
    }

    raw_products = request.item_search(query: params)
    hashed_products = raw_products.to_h

    # puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].collect{ |i| i['ItemAttributes']['Title'] }
    # puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].collect{ |i| i['DetailPageURL'] }
    # puts hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].collect{ |i| i['LargeImage']['URL'] }

    @products = []

    @products = hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
      product = OpenStruct.new
      product.name = item['ItemAttributes']['Title']
      product.url = item['DetailPageURL']
      product.image_url = item['LargeImage']['URL']

      @products << product 
    end
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Products from Amazon Product Advertising API</h1>
<% if @products.any? %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product">
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), product.url %>
      <%= link_to product.name, product.url %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't turn the entire Amazon hash into an `OpenStruct`.  And since `product.name` is `nil` you can't do a find on it.

Instead, just loop through the Amazon items, assign them to your product, and then add to the `@products` array:

```
@products = []
hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
  product = OpenStruct.new
  product.name = item['ItemAttributes']['Title']
  @products << product 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. Looks fresh. But I'm currently getting `undefined method `image_url' for #<Hash:0x848402e0>`. Have updated my question. Thoughts?

Comment: Don't assign `@products` to the results of the `each` loop.  This will cause you to actually set `@products` to the last element that was looped through.  So just change `@products = hashed_products...` to `hashed_products...`

Comment: Oh man. It worked! Seeing those products filling up my browser really brought tears to my eyes. I won't forget this @steakchaser, please let me buy you a drink sometime. Thanks again!

Comment: I've decided I want to convert this XML to JSON so perhaps I can parse it in a more beautiful manner. Do let me know what you think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997733/convert-amazon-xml-to-json-in-rails-and-parse-with-openstruct